# Google ReCaptcha and Parsley

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, recaptcha, parsley.js

I have a page in that I would like do not permit submitting without fillinig-in the captcha...

How should it work with Parsley.js? what field should I declare as required?

I have a callback JS function that returns "TRUE" when the captcha field is validated (used in ASP.NET Razor webpage), like this:

```js
function captchaCallback(response) {
  //console.log('the response is: ' + response);
  $.post("@(Model.Url)", {
    response: response,
    remoteip: "@HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress"
  }, function(data) {
    console.log("data success: " + data.response);
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
  <script src="http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="?" method="POST" data-parsley-validate>
    <input type="email" data-parsley-required />
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key" 
         data-callback="captchaCallback"></div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a perfect solution, but here's what I did:

1. Add a hidden input field with no default value.  If you submit the form (assuming parsley is doing its thing), it'll display an error.

`<input type="hidden" name="completed_captcha" id="completed_captcha" required />`

2. Setup a callback on the captcha (like you did above) and verify the captcha using ajax.  If the captcha validates, give `input#completed_captcha` a value.  If it fails, remove `input#completed_captcha`'s value.

That should do the trick, but in an effort to make it slightly harder for nefarious bots, I went one step further and added additional validation.

1. Create another hidden input somewhere on the page (outside of the form) and set the value to some random value.  I placed mine just before `</body>`.

`<input type="hidden" name="hello_bot" id="hello_bot" value="stroll snort birdie of latch taft">`

2. Modify `input#completed_captcha` to compare against our new hidden string.  Like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="completed_captcha" id="completed_captcha" required data-parsley-equalto="#hello_bot" />`

3. And finally, change your callback to set the value to match the value in `input#hello_bot`.

Hope this helps.